# Is it safe to use SQLalchemy with gevent?

Tags: python, thread-safety, sqlalchemy, gevent

I know that some database drivers and other libraries providing connection to external services are incompatible with coroutine-based network libraries. However, I couldn't find out if SQLAlchemy can be safely used with such libraries (namely, **gevent**), and if any workarounds should be applied to exclude possible errors.

Can you either tell me that or point me to an article where I can read this information? An additional 'thank you' if the provided answer also contains explanation of the mechanics of why it is okay or why it isn't. :-)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Did you try searching [gevent google group for SQLAlchemy](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/gevent/SQLAlchemy)?

I found this report of using [SQLAlchemy + mysql-connector](http://groups.google.com/group/gevent/msg/0c3e638532a63a6f) successfully and this of using [SQLAlchemy + psycopg2](http://groups.google.com/group/gevent/msg/b685a58ba81a7e30) successfully (make sure you've [read this](http://groups.google.com/group/gevent/browse_thread/thread/e77df0ceb9cbd05b/b7422f27daae4344))

I would think SQLAlchemy should be safe to use with gevent as long as the database driver that SQLAlchemy uses is safe, but I've not tried it myself and only basing this on the reports from other users.

Comment: Thank you, just the information I needed. And also thank you for developing gevent :)

Comment: I recommend to use mysql.connector. psycopg2 can have some problems.

Comment: I used psycopg2 with gevent and did not encounter any problems. If you can reproduce them, feel free to post in gevent google group or issue tracker.